# How to show product specification in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart to show some computer products online. When any user clicks on details of a product I want to show my computers specification in a table just the way like in the following image.

I have tried to use the "Product Type" option in virtuemart but it doesn't appear like following at all. Is there any extension to do this or there is other ways to get it done. Would you please kindly help me ?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot looks like a Product Attributes list with custom HTML/CSS. It's a template system, so find the correct template for your Attribute list and edit it.

Comment: Tthank you very much SMacFadyen for your answer. This may be a very stupid question to ask but but still.. would you please kindly give me a link to download a non commercial template for my product attribute list?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any, but Virtuemart comes with it's own very bog standard templates, check the 'default' theme directory in /components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/product_details/includes/addtocart_advanced_attribute.tpl.php, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with product types - you need to create a flypage for the product type that is laid out the way you want (as in your image).  When the product details page is displayed, it will locate that flypage, populate it, and put it into the product details page with the product_type info that you've supplied.  (We do this *all* the time, so it's just a case of making sure you're specifying the right flypage for the product with the associated product_type)

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin **Tabs and Slider** from [Joomlaworks](http://joomlaworks.net)